# Clicks in one UpdatePanel affects other UpdatePanels on same page

Tags: wffm, webforms

I am using `WFFM` webforms rendering with `Sitecore 8.1`. I don't want to do a full page reload on form post so added an update panel. The challenge is the update panel is affecting click events of another update panel. Did anyone face similar issue?

**Setup:**

1. Sitecore 8.1 with WFFM installed
2. using webforms
3. The layout has `<sc:placeholder`
4. On the blog landing page added WFFM webform rendering
5. On the same page have one other update panel for loading `View More` blogs.

Comment: Can you post a few exerts of how you have set up the UpdatePanels in your files, please?

Comment: hi @Mark, I have limited access to codebase and was helping other team. I will pull the code snippets and share

Comment: Update panels do a full page postback, they just mask it behind some tricky javascript. The entire page lifecycle will run on all controls.

Answer (score 1):

Update panels have their UpdateMode property set to Always by default, so they'll fire on any post back, even from another update panel.  You'll want to set it to Conditional. Conditional will update only if a child control or child update panel is the thing triggering the post back.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mschray/2013/06/05/update-panel-update-mode-always-vs-conditional-or-why-is-my-ajax-control-losing-focus/

Comment: That is true about UpdateMode. I have modified it to Conditional and started using the `<Triggers>` along with setting "ChildrenAsTriggers" set to false.

Comment: @phani Does it mean that this answer solved your problem? If it did, please [**mark it as accepted**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/183720). If it didn't, then you'll need to clarify what else you're missing.

Comment: @Dmytro issue is not yet resolved. I will followup with the team tomorrow to understand the progress. Temporarily we are moving forward with full page reload for WFFM form to not affect the delivery timelines.